# Why MethodHandle is slow than Reflection in JDK 1.8?

Tags: java, reflection, methodhandle

I have two performance tests using JMH. The code is very easy,one is using Java Reflection,Another is using MethodHandle(Introduced in JDK1.7),By The way,isEmptyMethod and MH_isEmpty is declared as static final,like this:

```
private static final MethodHandle MH_isEmpty;
private static final Method isEmptyMethod;

static {
    try {
        MH_isEmpty = MethodHandles.publicLookup().findVirtual(String.class, "isEmpty", MethodType.methodType(boolean.class));
        isEmptyMethod = String.class.getDeclaredMethod("isEmpty");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

`   Java Reflection:

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
public void testReflectionGetIsEmpty() throws Exception {
    isEmptyMethod.setAccessible(false);
    final Object result = isEmptyMethod.invoke("SmartLee");
}
```

`
MethodHandle:

```
@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
public void testFindVirtual() throws Throwable {
    final MethodHandle isEmpty = MH_isEmpty.bindTo("SmartLee");
    isEmpty.invoke();
}
```

Beblow is the performance results:
[performance results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwt6e.png)

According to [JDK docs.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html)Why MethodHandle is not faster than java reflection?
What's wrong with above code?

Comment: `MH_isEmpty.bindTo("SmartLee");` will create a new `MethodHandle`. Every time. Try `boolean result = (boolean) MH_isEmpty.invokeExact("SmartLee");`. Also, your reflection test may not be actually calling the method - it might be determined that it has no side effects. You should return the result of of the invocation. And parameterize it - in your current setup the JIT might reduce the code to a simple `return true` otherwise.

Comment: Thanks,Johannes. I add some log message that will 'consume' the result. And This will prevent JIT optimization.Now the result is intended.Thanks again for your advice.

Comment: 1. @Benchmark()
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
    void testReflectionGetIsEmpty() throws Exception {
        isEmptyMethod.setAccessible(false);
        final Object result = isEmptyMethod.invoke("SmartLee");
        log.info("The result of testReflectionGetIsEmpty is:{}",result);
    } 2. @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
    void testFindVirtual() throws Throwable {
        final MethodHandle isEmpty = MH_isEmpty.bindTo("SmartLee");
        Object result = isEmpty.invoke();
        log.info("The result of testFindVirtual is:{}",result);
    }

Comment: And 3 this the performance result. It is now intended.3.Benchmark                                          Mode  Cnt           Score          Error  Units
JMHSample_01_HelloWorld.testFindVirtual           thrpt    5       26213.457 ±    21430.137  ops/s
JMHSample_01_HelloWorld.testReflectionGetIsEmpty  thrpt    5       23876.432 ±    29526.599  ops/s
JMHSample_01_HelloWorld.wellHelloThere            thrpt    5  1402721640.465 ± 99207546.747  ops/s

Comment: Are you sure that you are not measuring how fast logging is now? Please either use a blackhole or simply `return` the result (where JMH will take care).

Comment: Thanks Johannes. I have changed the test to return the value and the logging go away.The performance result is very interesting as below:

Comment: Benchmark                                          Mode  Cnt           Score           Error  Units
JMHSample_01_HelloWorld.testFindVirtual           thrpt    5   233366711.254 ±  21866604.586  ops/s
JMHSample_01_HelloWorld.testReflectionGetIsEmpty  thrpt    5    46304374.560 ±   5983090.448  ops/s
JMHSample_01_HelloWorld.wellHelloThere            thrpt    5  1430612460.532 ± 112317387.739  ops/s

Comment: Now the MethodHandle'way is even faster than the Java Reflection'way.Thank you,Johannes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)